# Css первый/второй/третый слова из тега p изменить размер

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как можно изменить из тег p
Первую, вторую и третью букву

Сейчас есть номер телефона в теге p, хочу код оператора сделать жирным... код оператора взять в отдельный класс, не вариант..

Также есть еще вариант first-letter - у этого нет возможности изменить и второй/третий.

Comment: _"... код оператора взять в отдельный класс, не вариант.."_ Если Вы допускаете применение JS, то примерно такой вариант и получится - обернёте в тег с инлайн-стилями.

Comment: Интересует решение через is, думаю так возможно.                       Дело в том что номер телефона выводится из перемен, поэтому отдельно взят номер оператор, не вижу смысла.. еще клиент в дальнейшем может изменить номер из админки

Comment: Приведите формат номера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let p = document.querySelector('p');
let phone = p.innerText;
let result = `<span style="font-weight:bold">${phone.slice(0,3)}</span>${phone.slice(3)}`
p.innerHTML = result;
```

```html
<p>90586549878</p>
```

Comment: Круто, работает. Спасибо.